# About Minimum Spanning Tree Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

Is there an algorithm better (More optimal,faster) than Prime and [Kruskal's algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree#Faster_algorithms

Answer (score 0):

Prime's algorithm and Kruskal's algorithms works really fast if it is implemented well. Try to use optimal data structures for your data set case.
In really you don't need in more faster algorithm in most cases.

If you need in parallel implementation of algorithm, than use [Borůvka's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bor%C5%AFvka%27s_algorithm).

If you need the theory-fastest algorithm, than check [Decision trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree#Optimal_algorithm) algorithm.

And there is special case with linear [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree#Linear-time_algorithms_in_special_cases).

Comment: which one the best for complex network with very large input ?

Comment: For a graph with V vertices E edges, Kruskal's algorithm runs in O(E log V) time and Prim's algorithm run in O(E + V log V) amortized time. So, count E, V and decide that's one is better. If there is much vertex, but not much edges, than use Prim's. If there is much more vertex, than use Kruskal. And use (or write yourself) good implementation of this algorithm, because a constant is very important and bad implementation could be very slow. If input is really large and you have Xeon with 12 cores (or cluster with many instances), than try to use Boruvka's algorithm.